# how to estimate the gas price while performing bridge using Axelar network?

Tags: solidity, gas-estimate, bridge

I am using the Axelar network to transfer tokens from chain A to chain B I am using the `function callContractWithToken` in the Axelar network I need to figure out the gas fee which I should send to the Axelar network so I can be executed successfully I am ready to pay gas in Native token MATIC and well as the token which is being transferred.

I have already explored the Doc but it does not list the functionality of how the gas calculation can be done On chain? It has the SDK which can be used locally but I think that is not the best way to calculate the gas.

Answer (score 0):

Is this to build a dapp on Axelar? If you’re just trying to bridge assets personally - I’d check out Cypher Wallet. EVM + cosmos bridges for $1-2. Alternate but more expensive and slower bridges are multi chain but gets the job done

Answer (score 0):

Hey try out `estimateGasFee()` from axelarjs for this.
https://docs.axelar.dev/dev/axelarjs-sdk/axelar-query-api#estimategasfee
As is defined here

```
 public async estimateGasFee(
    sourceChainId: EvmChain | string,
    destinationChainId: EvmChain | string,
    sourceChainTokenSymbol: GasToken | string,
    gasLimit: number = DEFAULT_ESTIMATED_GAS,
    gasMultiplier = 1.1,
    minGasPrice = "0",
    gmpParams?: GMPParams
  ): Promise<string | AxelarQueryAPIFeeResponse>
```

Currently there is no way to know the gas amount on both chains from within solidity code on a single chain. Just a heads up though any gas that you overpay in a cross chain transaction with axelar will be refunded to you so it is better to pay more than less and just leverage the refund to make life easier.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).